# Get json data in php in different variable

Tags: php, json

I am unable to get data from json in different variable

```
$outputData= json_encode($posts); //[{"post_content":"asdcsswad","post_title":"sanjog"}]

$post_content=$outputData->post_content;
$post_title=$outputData->post_title;
```

both variable comes to blank

Comment: use json_decode().

Comment: You have an ***array*** of objects. It's `$outputData[0]->...`, or you want to loop through all array items.

Comment: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string,

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode`

```
$data = json_decode($outputData);
$post_content = $data['post_content'];
$post_title = $data['post_title'];
```

`json_decode` returns an array, not an object.

Though why don't you just use `$posts` if you're trying to use it in PHP?

Comment: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string,